# Indy POP3 place Header in TMemo

Tags: delphi, indy, email, pop3

I would like to retrieve the header text from a POP3 message into a TMemo.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
try
IdPOP31.Connect();
MsgCount := IdPOP31.CheckMessages;
for i:= 1 to MsgCount do
begin
try
 FMailMessage := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
 IdPOP31.Retrieve(i,FMailMessage);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('Mesage #: ' + IntToStr(i);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('From name: ' + FMailMessage.From.Name);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('From address: ' + FMailMessage.Sender.Address);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('Subject: ' + FMailMessage.Subject);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('From:' + FMailMessage.From.Address);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('Recipients: ' + FMailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses);
// HOW DO I GET THE HEADER ???????
 Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Body.Text);
 Memo1.Lines.Add('=================================================');
finally
 FMailMessage.Free;
end;
IdPOP31.Disconnect;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Headers`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdMessage_Headers.html) property of the message, which is a [`TStringList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TStringList) descendant. So to add header values for the message to your memo you can use one of the following statements:

```
// either you can use AddStrings method
Memo1.Lines.AddStrings(IdMessage1.Headers);
// or add it as string list's text e.g.
Memo1.Lines.Add(FMailMessage.Headers.Text);
```

Comment: Do note that MIME encoded emails can have multiple layers of headers.  The `TIdMessage.Headers` is just the top-level headers that appliy to the overall email as a whole. In the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection, each `TIdMessagePart` object has its own local `Headers` as well. Likewise, in a MIME encoded email, the body text is rarely stored in the `TIdMessage.Body`. It usually has the MIME preamble stored in it instead and the actual body text is stored in a separate `TIdText` object within the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection.